# Unbound Expression works as not expected in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Faced an issue where unbound expressions are not working as expected. Below is the scenario.

Parent component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" controller="test1" >   
<aura:attribute name="campingItem" type="Camping_Item__c" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Camping_Item__c'}" />    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>    <aura:attribute name="campingItemList" type="Camping_Item__c[]"/>


    <c:CampingItemList campingItems="{#v.campingItemList}" campingItem = "{#v.campingItem}"/>   

</aura:component>
```

Parent Controller:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get('c.getcampingItems');  

        // Configure response handler
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();

            if(state === "SUCCESS") { 
                console.log('Working: ' + state); 
                component.set('v.campingItemList', response.getReturnValue()); 
                console.log('list: ' + component.get('v.campingItemList'));
            } else {
                console.log('Problem getting account, response state: ' + state);
            }
        }
        $A.enqueueAction(action);               

        component.set('v.campingItem.Name', 'check1'); 
    }
});
```

Child Component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" controller="test1"> 
  <aura:attribute name="campingItems" type="Camping_Item__c[]"/>

<aura:attribute name="campingItem" type="Camping_Item__c" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Camping_Item__c'}" />       

<ui:message aura:Id="msg" title="Error" class="slds-hide" severity="confirm" closable="true">        Successfully deleted ID    </ui:message>   

ABC = {!v.campingItem.Name} 

</aura:component>
```

Here, we are getting that value of the attribute `campingItem` in the child which we are setting it in the `doInit` of the parent i.e. `check1` which is not supposed to be as per the developer guide as it is the unbound expression. But with list `campingItemList` its working as expected mean not getting the value.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below documentation link which very clearly says if you are going to use init events to load data for attributes which will get passed to other components then you have to use bound expressions. Unbound will not work for these cases

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_data_binding.htm

> Don’t use a component’s init event and client-side controller to
>   initialize an attribute that is used in an unbound expression. The
>   attribute will not be initialized. Use a bound expression instead. For
>   more information on a component’s init event, see Invoking Actions on
>   Component Initialization.
>
> Alternatively, you can wrap the component in another component. When
>   you instantiate the wrapped component in the wrapper component,
>   initialize the attribute value instead of initializing the attribute
>   in the wrapped component’s client-side controller.

Comment: I do agree but my question is why the value is passed from the doInit to the child  when we are using inbound expression. As it is not supposed to.

Comment: Your question is not clear? Didn't fully understand the part 'why the value is passed from the doInit to the child when we are using inbound expression'

Comment: Here if you check, i am using two attribute campingItem and campingItem the same attribute is used in the child component as well but using unBound expression I am passing these values to the child. In doInit of parent I am setting the value of both the attribute one is object and other is list<Object>.

Comment: Yep thats what the documentation says instead of 'campingItems="{#v.campingItemList}" ' change it to campingItems="{!v.campingItemList}" . That is the bound way of doing it

Comment: I am getting the same value of the object in the child component but I am using the unbound expression so It was not supposed mean I should not get any value of object in the child as I am setting it in the doInit. Also list<object> is working fine I am not getting the records in the list as aspected as it is an unbound expression

Answer (score -1):

When we use Unbound expression, it works as a one-way binding. So if we are passing any value as an attribute to child component, then both of the components have the same value(at initialization time), but then if we update the value in any of the components, it doesn't update to another one.